# Updating all values at a specific position in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary that looks like this

```
dict_ = {'ALPHA':(["data['ALPHA']", 'EMPTY'], 'N', 'N', 1),'BETA':(["data['BETA']", 'EMPTY'], 'N', 'N', 2),'GAMMA':(["data['GAMMA']", 'EMPTY'], 'N', 'N', 3)}
```

I want to add a constant to the final integer of each value tuple, to get

```
dict_ = {'ALPHA':(["data['ALPHA']", 'EMPTY'], 'N', 'N', 6),'BETA':(["data['BETA']", 'EMPTY'], 'N', 'N', 7),'GAMMA':(["data['GAMMA']", 'EMPTY'], 'N', 'N', 8)}
```

I tried

```
offset = 5
dict_.update((x, y[3]+offset) for x, y in dict_.items())
```

which results in

```
{'ALPHA': 6, 'BETA': 7, 'GAMMA': 8}
```

is there a better way of preserving the rest of the structure and only update the desired position ?

Comment: The problem is that your values here are tuples, and tuples are immutable.  If you want to keep the current structure, you're going to need to effectively overwrite each tuple.

Comment: Thanks, yes I thought so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
dict_ = {'ALPHA':(["data['ALPHA']", 'EMPTY'], 'N', 'N', 1),'BETA':(["data['BETA']", 'EMPTY'], 'N', 'N', 2),'GAMMA':(["data['GAMMA']", 'EMPTY'], 'N', 'N', 3)} 
final_dict = {a:tuple(list(b)[:-1]+[list(b)[-1]+5]) for a, b in dict_.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'ALPHA': (["data['ALPHA']", 'EMPTY'], 'N', 'N', 6), 'BETA': (["data['BETA']", 'EMPTY'], 'N', 'N', 7), 'GAMMA': (["data['GAMMA']", 'EMPTY'], 'N', 'N', 8)}
```

Which is the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

You can't update those values in place, because they are tuples. So you'll need to iterate through and regenerate each one with the offset.

```
for k, v in dict_.items():
    dict_[k] = v[:-1] + (v[-1] + offset,)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dict comprehensions to do that:

```
# Your input dict
dict_ = {
    'ALPHA':(["data['ALPHA']", 'EMPTY'], 'N', 'N', 1),
    'BETA':(["data['BETA']", 'EMPTY'], 'N', 'N', 2),
    'GAMMA':(["data['GAMMA']", 'EMPTY'], 'N', 'N', 3)}

# The offset for the last value of the tuple
offset = 5

# The updated dict
dict_offset = {
    key: value[:-1] + (value[-1] + offset, ) for key, value in dict_.items()}
```